# Jmeter sshmon plugin: check condition and interrupt the test

Tags: jmeter

using jmeter's SSHMON plugin, is it possible to check a condition and stop the test in case the condition is verified? for example I would like to interrupt the test if the available storage space is less than 10 percent ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible using SSHMON plugin however you can go for the following test elements combination:

1. [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler - to execute i.e. [`df` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_(Unix))
2. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - to fetch the available storage space information and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) - to fail the sample if the available storage space is within the acceptable range
4. [Auto-Stop Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right) - to stop the test if the number of failures will be > 1%